# How does the end of a sentence conveys the greatest emphasis, but the beginning conveys secondary emphasis?

Tags: emphasis

> Location of information within a sentence also affects emphasis. Generally, the end of a sentence conveys the greatest emphasis, the beginning of
> a sentence conveys secondary emphasis, and a parenthetic phrase or clause
> at a natural breaking point in the middle of the sentence conveys the least
> emphasis.

This is from the bottom of [page 39](https://books.google.com/books?id=MPdJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%22location+of+information+within+a+sentence%22&source=bl&ots=GbpZwsqKJ-&sig=ACfU3U0m_fw614ZBTemB9t4HUlKEEU3b_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi67YfN-_TsAhWRmOAKHZCHDRYQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) below. I had to do double take! I thought author flipped the order. Doesn't the BEGINNING of a sentence convey the GREATEST emphasis? But END of a sentence conveys SECONDARY emphasis?

[image]

Charles Calleros, Kimberly Holst. *Legal Method and Writing II: Trial and Appellate Advocacy, Contracts, and Correspondence* (Aspen Coursebook Series) (8 edn 2018).

Comment: Which sentence are you talking about?

Comment: @JRE I typed out that sentence now from my scan.

Answer (score 2):

No, the article is correct.

The end of a sentence has the greatest emphasis because the final words are the ones that linger with the reader.

Think of it like a piece of music: when all the instruments suddenly stop playing, the final note is the one that hangs in the air, echoing through the silence.

It's the same with writing. You should structure your sentences in such a way that whatever you wish to have the most impact hangs in the air for the reader. Sure, openings are important too, a good first sentence hooks the reader and makes them want to read on. But when they put the article or story down, it's the last line that will stay with them.